# Trace of Matrices multiplication

Tags: matrix-calculus, trace

Problem:
I want to obtain the trace:
$tr\left( {{A^H}{C^{ - 1}}A} \right)$

where $A$ is a $S \times L$ matrix, $A^H$ is conjugate transpose of $A$, $C$ is a $S \times S$ matrix, ${A^H} A=I$ identity matrix.

Thanks!

Comment: Is $S$ a matrix in Schur  form?

Comment: What do you know about $A A^{H}$ ? (which most write $ A A^{\dagger}$)

Comment: the $\left( {m,n} \right)$ element of $A$ is $\exp \left( { - j\frac{{2\pi mn}}{K}} \right),1 \le m \le K,1 \le n \le K$